# What's the most popular pronunciation of "minutiae"?

Tags: pronunciation

I looked this word up in the dictionary and there are multiple pronunciations:

- [maɪˈnju:ʃii:]
- [maɪˈnjuːʃiaɪ]
- [maɪˈnuʃiˌi]
- [mɪˈnuːʃiiː]
- [mɪˈnuːʃiaɪ]
- [maɪˈnuʃə]
- [mɪˈnuːʃə]

The easiest one to me is **[maɪˈnuʃə]**. In your opinion, what's the most popular one in the American English?

Comment: Have you ever used this word in your speech?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just say it however you want as it is a fairly rare word and the chances are your listener will not have heard it very often, if at all, and will themselves be unsure of how to say it. In fact it is so rare I cannot remember the last time I said it nor how I said it.

The problem here is that the word does not look much like an English word but rather like a Latin one so some people who have never heard it before will pronounce it how they pronounce Latin words. Unfortunately there is no clear consensus in my experience as to how to pronounce Latin in English. For instance some people pronounce Caesar to rhyme with seizer and some to rhyme with Kaiser. Others will pronounce it as if it were an English word but then have to decide what to do about the -ae ending which is unusual in English.